# Annotated emails in OS X

Tags: email

Is there some email client out there, which is well integrated into OS X, that has the ability to annotate emails? In particular, I would like to add a note, which will be linked to a specific message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at MailTags? I believe that in addition to tagging email messages you can also attach notes to messages. It is an add-on to Mail.app: http://indev.ca/MailTags.html. They also have a preview for Lion: http://indev.ca/MailTags3.html.

Comment: Indeed, that's the first solution came to mind. A very powerful plug-in.

Comment: Seems to be nice solution - I was hoping for something free... I didn't test the tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Mailsmith](http://www.mailsmith.org/) has the ability to add notes to messages. POP only (no IMAP), very configurable and scriptable.